# Toyota Yaris 2015 Automatic

Tags: brakes, noise

from last 2 months I am noticing intermittent Groaning(ghrrrrrerer) sound while applying breaks at slower speeds but this sound vanishes as I release the breake padel.
Changed the front break pads and get checked the rare wheel but couldn’t identify the issue.
It is not a constant sound but apears 2 out of 10 times when I press the break.
Is there any issue in ABS motor or sensor and is there any danger to the Breaks system.?

Comment: Do you feel slight vibration of the brake pedal along with the sound?

Comment: Did you check the rear pads? Had the front pads gone to metal before fitting the new ones?

Comment: @Juhist As the sound apears, there is the noticible vibration on the breake pedal

Comment: @Solar Mike The rare pads are fine and all the disks and Hubs went to workshop for polishing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the cause is. According to the comment "As the sound apears, there is the noticible vibrations" and according to the "ghrrrrrerer" description of the sound, this sound and brake pedal vibration comes from the ABS anti-lock braking system.

The system reduces pressure on the brake lines when it detects slipping. Slipping should not happen when braking moderately on dry pavement. Only very slippery conditions or heavy braking should cause wheel slipping.

Now, if you are braking moderately on dry pavement, the sound and vibration of the brake pedal is caused by some fault in the system, as in those conditions it is not possible that the wheels are slipping. Get your system inspected. The fault probably reduces the maximum possible braking power, and thus, the car may be a danger if driven on public roads.

I would only drive the car very carefully to a garage, preferably at a time when there is no heavy traffic on the roads.

Comment: Oh, and if this sound may occasionally happen at standstill, it may be a self-test of the ABS system: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41880/why-do-i-hear-sound-from-the-abs-on-rav4-hybrid-when-pressing-the-brake-pedal-at ...at least some hybrid cars to such a self-test. So, if it happens at standstill and lasts for less than a second, you're fine.

Comment: Thanks for the details, my car isn’t a hybrid one. Moreover the sound is not the same every time so the vibration. I didn’t hear that sound for a day when I changed the brake pads but started again very next day.